# In Evince, PDF text is not visible on many files

Tags: fonts

I found out that some PDF files, while opened in `evince`, do not show the contained text.
One can select the text, copy it and paste it somewhere else, but the text itself isn't rendered inside the opened PDF.

[image: invisible text in PDF]

Some other PDF files, however, can be rendered without problems.
[image: PDF of a research paper]

I think I saw this mentioned somewhere else, but the memory is too fragile to recall.
I've searched for this problem on *stackexchange*, without finding any references.

I've preemptively run `sudo fc-cache -f -v` to clear and regenerate the font cache, but the problem persists.

Has this happened to you? If so, how did you get around it?

Answer (score 3):

Allright, I found the fix:

It was about clearing and rebuilding the font cache with `fc-cache -f -v`, but run for the `flatpak` version of `evince`, so the command is:

`flatpak run --command=fc-cache org.gnome.Evince -f -v`

This may also work for any `flatpak` app with font problems, so a generic command would be:
`flatpak run --command=fc-cache domain.owner.appName -f -v`